# Why to I keep getting - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in Android?

Tags: android

I have read a bunch of posts on this, but I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening.
My activity loads fine initially. When I go to another app such as google maps, then come back into my app, it throws this error:

```
02-11 13:32:48.327    4323-4323/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.relProfile.FirstActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5008)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myapp.relProfile.FirstActivity.initHeader(FirstActivity.java:49)
        at com.myapp.relProfile.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
```

Here is my class code. The line with (*) at the front is where the null pointer is happening.
MyXMLParser.profileObj is a static field defined in another class. It seems this field is becoming null after the app goes into the background, but I'm not sure how to get this data back into the app as it never enters any of the lifecycle methods on reload.

```
package com.myapp.relProfile;

import com.myapp.R;
import com.myapp.utility.MyAbstractActivity;
import com.myapp.utility.MyXMLParser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstActivity extends MyAbstractActivity
{
    private RelativeLayout lay;
    private ListView lv;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_activity);           
        initHeader();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listInfo);
        degAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }       

    private void initHeader()
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout top = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rel_profile_header, null);
        System.out.println("HERE 1234");
        TextView name = (TextView) top.findViewById(R.id.nameLabel);
        *****name.setText(MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getEntityFullName());
        TextView info = (TextView) top.findViewById(R.id.infoLabel);
        info.setText(MyXMLParser.profileObj.getPrimaryRelationshipType());
        TextView title = (TextView) top.findViewById(R.id.titleLabel);
        title.setText(MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getJobTitle()+", "+MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getEmployer());
        TextView entityId = (TextView) top.findViewById(R.id.idLabel);
        entityId.setText("ID: "+ MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getSourceID());
        ImageView img = (ImageView)top.findViewById(R.id.relProfileImg);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headshot_placeholder2);
        lay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.profileHeaderDA);
        lay.addView(top);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your xml parser is probably returning null. getEntity() or getEntityFullName().

Comment: Put a log to print value of `getEntityFullName()` before calling `setText()` to check whether is it null or not ?

Comment: "but I'm not sure how to get this data back into the app as it never enters any of the lifecycle methods on reload" -- yes, it is. It is calling `onCreate()`. You can see that in your stack trace.

Comment: When I run my app in debug mode it never gets into the onCreate() when coming back into the app

Comment: Putting `Log.v` or `System.out` in your code and have an eagle eye on your stack trace can help only.

Comment: @ADJ - indeed, onCreate() is only called when a new Activity object needs to be created, not when an existing one is being restarted or resumed.  You don't really need a breakpoint debugger to fix this, but you can do so by launching the session through the debugger, or on recent devices there may be a settings option to not keep activities, which might help you get to see this code run if you are triggering it from an Intent or something which makes starting with the debugger difficult.

Comment: Yes, the system.out does output to the console both on initial load and after coming back into the app. I just don't know how I can access the MyXMLParser.profileObj object without it becoming null when the process goes into the background

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting this :

```
name.setText(""+MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getEntityFullName());
```

INSTEAD

```
name.setText(MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getEntityFullName());
```

> ```
>                    ********* Edited **************
> ```

Set your all textviews settext Like below:

```
name.setText(String.valueOf(MyXMLParser.profileObj.getEntity().getEntityFullName()));
```

And you are Done.

Comment: Error still remain in this line or changed to some other line?

Comment: The error moved to a different place, but there is still a null pointer exception being thrown. How does putting the empty string at the front prevent the exception in this instance?

Comment: This is because wherever you set the text You must remember that It only takes String values. So use of empty string means that you are giving them a String value.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am still wondering why the value of MyXMLParser.profileObj is getting set to null when my app goes into the background

Comment: Does my answer solved your problem or not? And No wonder It gives Nullpointer because compliler misunderstoods that there is no String.

Comment: no my problem still exists because the value of MyXMLParser.profileObj is getting set to null when my app goes into the background